# Set values in fields created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

have a simple registration form which can replicate the same N times for N inscriver people at once.

I have to set the values ​​of the `VALUE` field depending on selected `SELECT` option Participant independently for each registration form dynamically created option.

I tried several things but I can not make the event ( on change) fired from a given `SELECT` change only the value of that piece of form created in Javascript field.

I would like to create fields where `SELECT` fired an event that only alter its respective VALUE field according to the selected users in the `SELECT` option and that the trigger its `SELECT`, the `VALUE` field of the registration form to receive the value of the select value changed. I want this to happen independently created for all sections on the form .

I'm having the following problem, it seems that other SELECTS created dynamically follow the original select . Are not independent.

How can I fix this? The link below is the source code and the same

link: http://jsbin.com/lupeweha/5

Comment: You have not pasted _link_. __Moreover add your code here at StackOverflow.__

Comment: Sorry, the code is huge, I'll put.

Comment: Add only relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I see you actually fire the event on the select by calling the "select" element, which then fires the same event on ALL the selects! Create ids, and then call your functions independently.

```
function bindSelect(){
   $('select').on('change', function() {
   ....

   // hey, here all the selects get this function, on change.

   $('#main-select').on('change', function() {
   ...

   $('#other-select1').on('change', function() {
   ...

   $('#other-select2').on('change', function() {
```

Hope it helps.